# Распарсить xml документ без иерархии классов

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

У меня есть длинный xml файл, использовал JAXB. Но без создания java классов на каждый вложенный тег просто нереально.

Есть ли возможность просто взять xml и превратить его в джава объект без создания внутренних классов?

Например:
Кусок обрезанного xml документа:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/schemas/mrd-1.5.xsl"?>
<MRData xmlns="http://ergast.com/mrd/1.5" series="f1" url="http://ergast.com/api/f1/1990/1/results" limit="30" offset="0" total="35">
    <RaceTable season="1990" round="1">
        <Race season="1990" round="1" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_United_States_Grand_Prix">
            <RaceName>United States Grand Prix</RaceName>
            <Circuit circuitId="phoenix" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_street_circuit">
                <CircuitName>Phoenix street circuit</CircuitName>
                <Location lat="33.4479" long="-112.075">
                    <Locality>Phoenix</Locality>
                    <Country>USA</Country>
                </Location>
            </Circuit>
            <Date>1990-03-11</Date>
            <ResultsList>
                <Result number="27" position="1" positionText="1" points="9">
                    <Driver driverId="senna" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayrton_Senna">
                        <GivenName>Ayrton</GivenName>
                        <FamilyName>Senna</FamilyName>
                        <DateOfBirth>1960-03-21</DateOfBirth>
                        <Nationality>Brazilian</Nationality>
                    </Driver>
                    <Constructor constructorId="mclaren" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McLaren">
                        <Name>McLaren</Name>
                        <Nationality>British</Nationality>
                    </Constructor>
                    <Grid>5</Grid>
                    <Laps>72</Laps>
                    <Status statusId="1">Finished</Status>
                    <Time millis="6752829">1:52:32.829</Time>
                </Result>
                <Result number="4" position="2" positionText="2" points="6">
                    <Driver driverId="alesi" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Alesi">
                        <GivenName>Jean</GivenName>
                        <FamilyName>Alesi</FamilyName>
                        <DateOfBirth>1964-06-11</DateOfBirth>
                        <Nationality>French</Nationality>
                    </Driver>
                    <Constructor constructorId="tyrrell" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrrell_Racing">
                        <Name>Tyrrell</Name>
                        <Nationality>British</Nationality>
                    </Constructor>
                    <Grid>4</Grid>
                    <Laps>72</Laps>
                    <Status statusId="1">Finished</Status>
                    <Time millis="6761514">+8.685</Time>
                </Result>
```

Как это можно обойти? Без создания классов `ResultList` в нем `Result`, потом еще `Driver` и т.д.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html

В консоли запускаем:

`xjc ./path/to/xsd/file.xsd`

В папке `target/classes/your/package/` появятся требуемые классы.